# I am trying to populate spinner with values from array.My spinner is not displayig the dropDown Lost when executed !This is my code

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

Putting my code here..have created JSONArray'project' in the class and tried to put the elements from JSONArray in Spinner. But Spinner is not displaying me the dropdown list

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Spinner practiceSpin;
    Spinner projectSpin;
    JSONObject projDet;
    JSONArray projArr;


    private final static String JSON_DATA =
          "{" 
                   + "  \"project\": [" 
                   + "    {" 
                   + "      \"id\": \"1\"," 
                   + "      \"name\": \"xxxx\","                   
                   + "    }," 
                   + "    {" 
                   + "      \"id\": \"2\"," 
                   + "      \"name\": \"yyyy\","                                 
                   + "    {" 
                   + "      \"id\": \"3\"," 
                   + "      \"name\": \"zzzz\","
                   + "    {" 
                   + "      \"id\": \"4\"," 
                   + "      \"name\": \"hhhh\","
                   + "  ]" 
                   + "}"; 
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       try {
           projDet=new JSONObject(JSON_DATA);
           projArr=projDet.getJSONArray(JSON_DATA); 

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    practiceSpin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerPractice);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ar=      ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.practices,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    ar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    practiceSpin.setAdapter(ar);

    projectSpin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerProject);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_proj = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.array.practices, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,projArr);
```

/*"The constructor ArrayAdapter(MainActivity, int, int, JSONArray)
                                                                                                                                            is undefined" error*/

```
    adapter_proj.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    projectSpin.setAdapter(adapter_proj);


    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v){

            Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity1.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
         }
     });
    }
```

}

/*I am not able to rectify the error.Please Help*/

Answer (score 0):

> The constructor ArrayAdapter(MainActivity, int, int, JSONArray) is
>   undefined" error/

Because `ArrayAdapter`  takes `List` or `Array` as data-source but you are trying to pass `JSONArray`.

To show data from JSONArray first get all values from array to ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> arrData=new ArrayList<String>();
for(int n = 0; n < projArr.length(); n++)
{
    JSONObject object = projArr.getJSONObject(n);
     arrData.add(object.optString("name"));
}
```

Use `arrData` instead of `projArr` as data-source in Adapter constructor.